# Не получается добавить PaintListener к Canvas в SWT

Tags: java, многопоточность, canvas, swt

Начинаю дебажить этот кусок кода

```java
 public void redrawGraphic(Function func, int color){
        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {
                Rectangle clientArea = canvas.getClientArea();
                e.gc.setLineWidth(1);
                e.gc.setForeground(e.display.getSystemColor(color));
                for (int currFunc = 0; currFunc < func.size() - 1; currFunc++) {
                    if ((int)Math.round(abs(func.getPoint(currFunc).y)) 
                            <= clientArea.height/LINES_SPACE*currScale/2 + currPixelsCenterX + 1) {
                        int key0 = (int)Math.round(func.getPoint(currFunc).x 
                                / currScale * LINES_SPACE) + clientArea.width / 2;
                        int value0 = -(int)Math.round(func.getPoint(currFunc).y 
                                / currScale * LINES_SPACE) + clientArea.height / 2;
                        int key1 = (int)Math.round(func.getPoint(currFunc + 1).x 
                                / currScale * LINES_SPACE) + clientArea.width / 2;
                        int value1 = -(int)Math.round(func.getPoint(currFunc + 1).y 
                                / currScale * LINES_SPACE) + clientArea.height / 2;
                        e.gc.drawLine(key0 - currPixelsCenterX,  value0 + currPixelsCenterY,
                                key1 - currPixelsCenterX, value1 + currPixelsCenterY);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

При step over перескакивает через блок

```
new PaintListener() {}
```

При step into в переменных у canvas пишет "No such instance field: 'canvas' ", хотя это поле проинициализированно. Если убрать все содержимое блока -- результат тот же.

У меня есть подозрение, что виновата синхронизация.

```java
public void drawNewPoint(){
        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable () {
            public void run() {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    while (model.isReadyToDraw) {
                        condition.await();
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(model.getMsSleepTime());

                    model.isReadyToDraw = true;
                    System.out.println(model.sharedPoint.x + " " + model.sharedPoint.y);
                    model.addSharedLinearPoint();
//вот тут вызываю метод, листинг которого выше
                    graphicsController.redrawGraphic(model.getLinearFunction(), SWT.COLOR_GREEN); 
                    condition.signalAll();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                } finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Метод выше выполняется в классе, который реализует Runnable, где синхронизируется с другим потоком, осуществляющим вычисления.

В чем же причина?

Comment: а canvas где объявлена?

Comment: @dSH, в том же классе, где и redrawGraphic()

Comment: На английском сайте [подсказали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56096963/cant-add-paintlistener-to-canvas), что condition.await() и Thread.sleep() блокируют поток UI. Убрал, все более-менее работает